# Refresh User's Location - Swift 3

Tags: ios, delegates, swift3, location, cllocationmanager

I am having a problem with updating the location of the user after pressing a refresh button. I have the following code. The compiler doesn't show any error however the `print after refresh` is not working and there are no data. Can anybody point me the right direction how to fix it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   locationManager.requestLocation()
}

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      if let location = locations.first {
        print("Coordinates: \(location)")
      }  
   }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("errorer")
    }
```

Then I have the following refresh code:

```
@IBAction func refreshJobData(_ sender: Any) {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            print("Coordinates after Refresh: \(location)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expected to happen here. From the code provided it looks like you redefined a `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` function inside of your `refreshJobData`. Is that actually how you've structured your code? What if anything do you expect to call this nested inner function?

Comment: the func inside your refreshJobData won't be called just by being declared in there?

Comment: All you need to do in your refresh code is call `requestLocation` again and you will get a callback to your `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.